# Nginx does not separate URLs based on having or not having extensions

Tags: nginx

This is my Nginx configuration:

```
    location ~ \.[^/]+$ {
        add_header X-HAS-EXTENSION "true";
        root /PaydarSamane/Storage;
    }

    location ~ ^.*$ {
        add_header X-HAS-EXTENSION "false";
        add_header X-ADDING-EXTENSION "true";
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.webp;
    }

    location / {
        add_header X-IMAGE "true";
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        error_page 404 = @api;
        default_type image/webp;
        root /PaydarSamane/Storage;
    }

    location @api {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5200;
    }
```

Basically, this is what I want to do:

1. If the URL has extension, then go ahead and serve it as a static file
2. If it does not have extension, add `.webp` to the end of it
3. Now for the rewritten URL either serve it as a static file, or in case of 404, pass it to an API (reverse proxy) which will serve the image
4. When passing it to the API, remove the `.webp` from the end of the file

But for `https://storage.example.com/post/153` it returns the `X-HAS-EXTENSION: true` header.

Comment: Looking at your code, that's the only outcome. The second location matches anything and rewrites it to add `.webp`, which then matches the first location. The first location processes the request and adds `X-HAS-EXTENSION: true` when it returns the result to the client.

Comment: @RichardSmith, what should I do to fix it? I tried `break` and `last` after the rewrite, but none of them worked.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use `try_files` to directly test the requested URI, with and without `.webp` and redirect to `@api` on failure.

For example:

```
location / {
    root /PaydarSamane/Storage;
    try_files $uri $uri.webp @api;
}
```